# I'm trying to link hdf5 to c++ code (Mac)

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, hdf5

I have the files:
main.cpp, tools.cpp, tools.h, integrator.cpp, and integrator.h.

I have tried to link HDF5 to this code (it compiles/links just fine without hdf5 stuff).

Here's what I am using to compile:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c++1y -I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lhdf5 -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5_cpp  main.cpp tools.cpp integrator.cpp
```

The error I get is complete nonsense to me:

```
  "__ZN2H56H5FileC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjRKNS_17FileCreatPropListERKNS_15FileAccPropListE", referenced from:
      _main in cc76aLiD.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, sure enough, if I take out all the HDF5 commands in my code but keep the `#include "H5Cpp.h"` at the top of main.cpp it works. This seems odd to me because I would assume it would fail here too?

Anyone have any suggestions to try?
I'm using a Mac if that is relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want also link with `-lhdf5_hl_cpp`. If you had used cmake, as I suggested today, you would not have such issues.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I will learn cmake, I just don't have the time today as it seems pretty complicated. But if you recommend it that much, I'll look into it this weekend! Cheers!